# InnoSetup not creating program folders

Tags: qt, inno-setup

Im making an installer of my application using Innosetup.
Created app folder by windeployqt MinGW before using Innosetup:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rCnt.png)

After installing my program (with Innosetup installer):
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5SQ8.png)

App installer just puts all files from folders to main installation folder.
This makes app not working, because it can't find needed files located in directories that do NOT exist...

"Files" section of Innosetup file:

```
[Files]
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\pracownia.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\iconengines\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\imageformats\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\platforms\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\translations\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\background.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\D3Dcompiler_47.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\icon.ico"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\icon.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\libEGL.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\libGLESV2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\libstdc++-6.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\libwinpthread-1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\login-box.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\menu.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\opengl32sw.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\Qt5Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\Qt5Gui.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\Qt5Svg.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\Qt5Widgets.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\shadow.png"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\WinSCP.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
```

Do I have to add additional things to this file to make folders and paste proper files to them?

Comment: Note that there's no specification of some "root" source folder. So how do you expect Inno Setup compiler to magically detect that you want to maintain the directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the InnoSetup documentation, your `DestDir` parameter for the files that you want in subfolders should actually include the name of the desired subfolder.

So, probably something like

```
Source: "D:\qtprojects\compile\iconengines\*"; DestDir: "{app}\iconengines"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

You may want to peruse [said relevant documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/)